# Updating Notification Continuously

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, java-threads

Hello There I am a newbie for Android Development, working to learn it to my own!
I just want to update my notification in a Java Thread in my application (I am just learning and curious about how can I do it).

---

I have an activity, a simple thread to increment an Integer value. Then, I just want to show it in my Notification whenever the Integer value increments!
My Code is as:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        private final String LOG_KEY = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        private int c = 0;
        private boolean flag = true;
        private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        private NotificationManager notificationManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
               .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
               .setAutoCancel(false);

            builder.setOngoing(true);

            notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
            t.start();
        }//OnCreate ends

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            flag = false;
        }//stop ends

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            flag = false;
        }//destroy ends

        private class MyThread implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (flag) {
                    c+=1;
                    showNotification(Integer.toString(c) + " Counts");
                }//while ends
            }//run ends

            private void showNotification(String msg) {
                try {
                    //set the notification
                    builder.setContentText(msg);
                    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    Log.e("xmn", exp.toString());
                }//try catch ends
            }//showNotification ends

        }//private class ends
    }//MainActivity class ends here
```

---

**As from my code, the notification appears and updates the value! But the problem is that it freezes the device and application at a sudden!**

**I just want help for what I am doing wrong as I am a newbie and learning it to my own. Any help and idea will be highly appreciated!**

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating a notification and then continuously updating it as fast as you can from a thread.  It's really not designed for that.

The closest thing I can think of that would meet your use case is using a notification to display progress.  See this link:

[Displaying Progress in a Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Progress)

You might want to put some kind a rate limiter in your thread, unless you want your count to reach very high numbers very quickly.  Perhaps make the thread sleep for a second between updates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you produce too much notifications more then a device can consume.

For your goal (just learn) you can add a some pause between notifications like that:

```
private void showNotification(String msg) {
    try {
        //set the notification
        Thread.sleep(1000);  //set the pause

        builder.setContentText(msg);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        Log.e("xmn", exp.toString());
    }//try catch ends
}//showNotification ends
```